# Updating NSManagedObject attribute after DatePicker is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uidatepicker

My CoreData application uses two 'Date' fields to store date information. I am using UIDatePicker to select the date. When I am doing the validation for these two attributes, I can see that the 'Date' attributes are not modified until the ManagedObject is saved.

How can update these 'Date' attributes as soon as the the DatePicker values are changed?

```
- (BOOL)validateStartDate:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSDate *inputDate = *ioValue;

   if ([inputDate compare:self.endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
       if (outError != NULL) {
        // Error handling ****
       }
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateEndDate:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSDate *inputDate = *ioValue;

    if ([inputDate compare:self.startDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        if (outError != NULL) {
            // Error handling ***
        }
        return NO;
     }
     return YES;
}
```

This is the code I am using to validate both 'Start' and 'End' date. Here I want to save 'Start' or 'End' date every time a user changes it. So that the validation will work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender{
    yourManagedObject.date = [(UIDatePicker *)sender date];

    NSError *error;
    if([yourManagedObjectContext save:&error]){
        //didn't save
    }
}
```

Then hook up your date pickers sent event "valueChanged" to that

Comment: I don't want to save ManageObjectContext every time when user selects a date. (The user might change his mind and select another date before finally saving the context). Is there any built in method in NSManagedObject one like,                              -(BOOL)validate*****:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError          So that the method will be triggered as soon as the DatePicker value is changed.

Comment: I don't think there is a built in method that can achieve that for you, but if you take a look at mogenerator http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/
You can add that method to your managed object. Which will allow you to validate it anytime you please. If you don't want to use mogenerator you can always create a category of your managed object and implement the method in that. I hope this is what you are looking for otherwise let me know.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the help. Mogenerator is really confusing to me so I am trying Category. So far it is doing great.